# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote the following compiled query:

```
public static Func < Modal.Entities, string, IQueryable < Modal.Staff > >
        MyQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((Modal.Entities U, string StaffNo) => U.Staff.Where(a => a.StaffNo == StaffNo));
```

and used the following statement to invoke the compiled query:

```
Modal.Staff abc = MyQuery(context, StaffNo);
```

But I got the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable ' to 'Modal.Staff'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns System.Linq.IQueryable, but you are trying to assign it to Modal.Staff. Change your query to return single result:

```
 MyQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((Modal.Entities U, string StaffNo) => 
      U.Staff.Where(a => a.StaffNo == StaffNo).FirstOrDefault());
```